# How to calculate normal for the cylindrical bevel

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I am trying to add bevel to a cylinder , but i am have an issue with calculating the normals for the bevel

the

[image]

this is how i am calculating the data for vertices

```
      struct Vertices
     {
      float x;
      float y;
      float z;
     }

     float pieStartAngle = 0.0 * (M_PI / 180.0f);
    float angleCircle = 0.0f;

    // First fill all the position of vertices
    for (int k = 0; k < totalNumberOfPies; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < segmentPerPie + 1; i++)
        {
            Vertices temp;
            float initialAngle = pieStartAngle;
            angleCircle = (stdvecValuePercent[k] / 100.0f) * totalAngle;
            float angle = initialAngle + ((angleCircle *(M_PI / 180)) * i / segmentPerPie);
            float x, y, z, tx, ty, tz;
            float innerX, innerY, innerZ, innerTx, innerTy;
            x = cos(angle)  * (radius - bevel);
            y = sin(angle)  * (radius - bevel);
            z = 0.0;
            temp.x = x;
            temp.y = y;
            temp.z = z;
            vertices.push_back(temp);

            x = cos(angle)  * radius;
            y = sin(angle)  * radius;
            z = 0.0 + bevel;
            temp.x = x;
            temp.y = y;
            temp.z = z;
            vertices.push_back(temp);
        }
        pieStartAngle += angleCircle * (M_PI / 180);
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

this is how i am calculating the data for normals , i am taking the cross product of three verices to get the vector perpendicular to the face.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
    {       
        glm::vec3 vec1 = glm::vec3(vertices[i].x - vertices[i + 1].x, vertices[i].y - vertices[i + 1].y, vertices[i].z - vertices[i + 1].z);
        glm::vec3 vec2 = glm::vec3(vertices[i].x - vertices[i + 2].x, vertices[i].y - vertices[i + 2].y, vertices[i].z - vertices[i + 2].z);
        glm::vec3 crossProduct = glm::cross(glm::normalize(vec1), glm::normalize(vec2));
        crossProduct = glm::normalize(crossProduct);
        bevelData.push_back(vertices[i].x);
        bevelData.push_back(vertices[i].y);
        bevelData.push_back(vertices[i].z);
        bevelData.push_back(crossProduct.x );
        bevelData.push_back(crossProduct.y );
        bevelData.push_back(crossProduct.z);
        bevelData.push_back(0.0);
        bevelData.push_back(0.0);

    }
```

Comment: What are "totalNumberOfPies" and "segmentPerPie" what's a pie? Do you mean a triangle?

Comment: @Makogan pie is a semicircle ,  you can thinkof total number of totalNumberOfPies as 3 and segmentPerPie as 32 , this code will form a circle which would be a combination of 3 semi circles.

Comment: any reason you are reasoning about your shape that way vs doing a parametrization of the shape?

Comment: @Makogan i want to add different colors to the cylinder that is the reason i am using  thisshape but it is still a cylinder , my question is reagarding how to get the normals for the beveled part.

Comment: Can you print the normals as the color? I suspect you may be flipping the sign of the normals